# "info command rtExMath" in Tk with vtk

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, vtk

I am new for `Tcl/Tk`. I am using `vtk`  with `Tk` command window for running vtk tcl/tk examples. Here is a code which include Tk expression as condition of `if` and I am not getting it.

```
if { [info command rtExMath] != "" } {
    ##Do something related VTK
}
```

I have explored `info` of Tk but there is a combination with keyword `command` and also no any good explanation I found for `rtExMath`. 
Please explain me above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`info commands`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/info.htm#M9) command (`info command` is just an unambiguous prefix) returns a list of all commands, or a list of all commands that match the given [glob pattern](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M35). In the case you're looking at, the glob pattern is actually going to be a string-equality check (and is even optimised to such internally); there's no glob metacharacters in it. The result of that is that `[info command rtExMath] != ""` is a condition that is true exactly when the command `rtExMath` exists.

Tcl itself does not define any command called `rtExMath`; I conclude that it must be part of some specialist extension or application. However, Googling makes me suspect that it is actually a somewhat-standard name for an instance of the [`vtkMath` class](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkMath.html) in Vtk, but I don't really know for sure. (I'm guessing that the binding of that class to Tcl was done by SWIG…)

Comment: Oh yes it's just to check if that class exists or not. I have checked info command _SomeExistingVTKClass_ and it returned string but for non existing it returned empty string. Thanks!!!!